# Does Microsoft.OData.Client change the service port on PATCH requests?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2, odata, appharbor

So I was working on the client side, pulling odata V4 records with a Microsoft.OData.Client auto generated container, everything was going great

When I thought, I need to patch a record, that's ok I'll just

```
_container.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.None);
```

and it started failing with

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   176.34.122.158:15737"

In the client, something, still don't know what was changing the port from 443 to 15737 and changing the URI scheme to plain http

Visual studio IIS express uses ports other than 80 and 443 and the problem only appeared when I started pointing the client at the deployed service in AppHarbor so I suspect this change in ports only happens when the container was set with a uri with a default port but I'd need to do further testing.

If you, reading this have any idea on what could be causing the uri in the container to change, I'd love to know.

**The dirty dirty way to fix the symptoms:**

when adding the authentication token to the header, force the uri back into the desired port

```
public static void OnBuildingRequest(object sender, BuildingRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Properties.Settings.Default.ODataToken);

        if (e.RequestUri.IsDefaultPort == false)
        {
            UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder(e.RequestUri);
            ub.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
            ub.Port = 443;
            e.RequestUri = ub.Uri;
        }
    }
```

yes the token is stored in the properties i promise I'll be good and encrypt it later... maybe :P

**Edit 20/7**

The support staff at Appharbour has kindly taken an interest and asked for some clarification so here goes, now with 100% more doodles:

**Architecture:**

Server: XXXX.apphb.com (SQL + Entity Framework (Model) + WEB API 2 OData V4 (Controler))

Client: desktop client (WPF using Microsoft.Odata.Client, with proxies created with OData v4 Client Code Generator)

Server <--- HTTPS with token authentication ---> Client

**Workflow (client side):**

Authenticate -> GET -> PATCH

Create container during WPF page construction:

```
public partial class PageLibrary : Page
{
    Uri _uri;
    Default.Container _container;
    List<BookScore> _bookscores;

    public PageLibrary()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _uri = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.ServerMetadataUri);  //<-- https://XXXXXX.apphb.com/Metadata/
        _container = new Default.Container(_uri);
        _container.BuildingRequest += (sender, e) => Authentication.OnBuildingRequest(sender, e); 
    }
```

User requests BookScores causing:

```
_bookscores = (_container.BookScores).ToList();
```

Client prepares the request to send a GET, the BuildingRequestEventArgs e points at the default port

e.RequestUri.Port = 443

User changes a value and saves:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var bookscore in _bookscores)
        {
            _container.UpdateObject(bookscore);
        }
        _container.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.None);
    }
```

Still pointing at right port

[_container.BookScores.RequestUri.Port = 443](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vClzC.jpg)

Client prepares the request to send a PATCH, (notice how the argument now carries a different port)

[e.RequestUri.Port = 15747](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVp9J.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

According to AppHarbor support:

> the problem indeed is that the server is giving the client the wrong
>   URL. It seems that OData/WebAPI doesn't support the X-Forwarded-Proto
>   header out of the box. That causes issues since the OData client
>   software doesn't continue to use the URL you specify when setting up
>   the OData context -- it reads the metadata, which will contain the
>   wrong scheme, hostname and port

```
public class ForwardedProtocolHeadersHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var forwardedProtocolHeader = request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x =>
        string.Equals(x.Key, "X-Forwarded-Proto", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(forwardedProtocolHeader.Key))
    {
        var isHttps = string.Equals(forwardedProtocolHeader.Value.Single(), Uri.UriSchemeHttps, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        var urlBuilder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri)
        {
            Scheme = isHttps ? Uri.UriSchemeHttps : Uri.UriSchemeHttp,
            Port = isHttps ? 443 : 80,
        };

        request.RequestUri = urlBuilder.Uri;
    }

    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
}
```

complete explanation:

https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/83648-odata-web-api-2-patch-not-working